# Closure of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to find the closure the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of
$$B = \{x \times y \mid x>0 \ \text{and}\ y  \neq 0\}$$

I want to prove that $\overline{B} = \mathbb{R^+_0} \times \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

First we will prove that $\overline{B} \supset \mathbb{R^+_0} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Let $0 \times 0 \in \mathbb{R^+_0} \times \mathbb{R}$. If $r >0$ we have that $\frac{r}{2} \times \frac{r}{2} \in B_d(0\times 0, r) \cap B$, hence $0 \times 0 \in \overline{B}$.

Let $0 \times y \in \mathbb{R^+_0} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $y \neq 0$. If $r >0$  we have $\frac{r}{2} \times y \in B_d(0 \times y, r) \cap B$, hence $0 \times y \in \overline{B}$.

Let $x  \times 0 \in \mathbb{R^+_0} \times \mathbb{R}$ with $x>0$. If $r>0$ we have $x \times \frac{r}{2} \in B_d(x \times 0, r) \cap B$, hence $x \times 0 \in \overline{B}$.

Now we will prove that $\overline{B} \subset \mathbb{R^+_0} \times \mathbb{R}$.

I have attempted upto this. Please correct my solution and advise me further.

Comment: Why do you insist in writing $x\times y$ instead of $(x,y)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir, I was solving Munkres's exercises...the author uses the notation, so I was using like that....

Comment: It is a non-standard notation and so less users will understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x,y)\in\Bbb R_0^+\times\Bbb R$, take $r>0$; then $\left(x+\frac r2,y\right)\in B$ and $\left(x+\frac r2,y\right)\in B_r\bigl((x,y)\bigr)$. Therefore, $(x,y)\in\overline B$.

And if $(x,y)\notin\Bbb R_0^+\times\Bbb R$, then $x<0$, and so$$(x',y')\in B_{-x}\bigl((x,y)\bigr)\implies x'<0\implies(x',y')\notin B.$$So $B_{-x}\bigl((x,y)\bigr)\cap B=\emptyset$, and therefore $(x,y)\notin\overline B$.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. You wrote $(x',y')\in B_{-x}\bigl((x,y)\bigr)\implies x'<0$. Is it because of $(x',y')\in B_{-x}\bigl((x,y)\bigr)$, so by $d_2$ metric we have $\sqrt{(x^\prime -x)^2 + (y^\prime - y)^2} <|x|$, thus $(x^\prime -x)^2 + (y^\prime - y)^2 < x^2 \implies (x^\prime - x)^2 < x^2 \implies x^\prime -x < |x| = -x \implies x^\prime <0$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.